# Why Exception class behaves like unchecked exception and does not require try block to throw any checked or even any exceptions at all?

Tags: java, exception

Exception is a checked exception. Why I can write `catch (Exception e)` when respective try block does not throw anything? This trick is not allowed with any other checked exception like IOException. Some books say that Throwable also shall be considered a checked exception, but it behaves just like Exception.

```
void f() {
        try {

        } catch (Exception e) {   // fine!


        }
    }


void f() {
        try {

        } catch (Throwable e) {   // also fine!


        }
    }
```

P.S. Found this in [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.2.3):

> It is a compile-time error if a catch clause can catch checked
>   exception class E1 and it is not the case that the try block
>   corresponding to the catch clause can throw a checked exception class
>   that is a subclass or superclass of E1, **unless E1 is Exception or a
>   superclass of Exception.**

Comment: Because these are supertypes of `RuntimeException`.

Comment: Because `Exception` and `Throwable` are superclasses to `RuntimeException`, which can be thrown anywhere without being declared.

Comment: *Some books say that Throwable also shall be considered a checked exception, but it behaves just like Exception.* They're both checked exceptions.

Comment: For checked exceptions there is a rule that I cannot catch them unless they maybe thrown from respective try block. Throwable and Exception seem to be an exclusion from this rule, this is why I asked.

Comment: That's why we answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Louis Wasserman's comment is correct. Exception is the super class of RuntimeException. Thus, catching Exception also catches all unchecked exceptions.

Answer (score -1):

If you look into the code for `Exception`, you'll find that it extends Throwable:

```
public class Exception extends Throwable
```

Anything that can be `throw`n is a `Throwable`. Though this gives a level of flexibility since you can create a custom class that extends throwable (and throw that too). Exception is pretty much just a minimalistic wrapper around Throwable. So essentially:

```
try{
    //something here that goes wrong causing:
    throw new Exception("Thrown");
}catch(Throwable e){
    System.out.println("Caught");
}
```

Though catching an Exception will also work. But if you create a new class that extends Throwable, catching `Exception` will have no effect.

Which means, if you can catch an Exception as a general statement, you can also catch its superclass, being Throwable. Note that it is not a good practice to do so, but I am mentioning it because it is possible. If you have to catch something general, catch Exception, and not Throwable.

Comment: Catching Throwable also catches Error, which is a bad practice. Also, catching Exception does not catch Throwable.

Comment: @Steve11235 I never mentioned it was a good practice either. And I didn't say catching an exception catches throwables